# Регулярное выражение для поиска определённой буквы по всем символам в строке

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Добрый день! Помогите составить регулярное выражение для поиска нужной буквы или нескольких букв используя `String.matches();`

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("роза"); //0
list.add("лира"); //1
list.add("лоза"); //2

for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
{
    //удалять из списка строк все слова, содержащие букву «р»
    if (list.get(i).matches(".*р.*"))
    {
        list.remove(i);
    }
}
```

вывод на экран

```
лира
лоза
ираз
```

Вопрос как правильно составить регулярку, чтобы был поиск по всем символам в строке? Спасибо

Comment: `.*` не это вам нужно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Операция `matches` ищет полное совпадение. В вашем случае лучше воспользоваться [`find`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find()). Тогда регулярное выражение будет просто `р`:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("p");
if(regex.matcher(string).find()) // совпадение найдено
```

В вашей программе другая проблема. Когда вы удаляете запись из списка, последующие элементы сдвигаются, и вы в результате пропускаете элемент. Например, если вы удалили строку номер 2, то строка номер 3 станет строкой номер два и вы её пропустите, потому что на следующей итерации вы ещё раз увеличите индекс. Удалять из списка лучше итератором:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("p");
for(Iterator<String> it = list.iterator(); list.hasNext(); ) {
    String str = it.next();
    if(regex.matcher(str).find()) it.remove();
}
```

Так вы ничего не пропустите.

Если вы используете Java 8, всё ещё проще: есть специальный метод [`removeIf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-):

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("p");
list.removeIf(str -> regex.matcher(str).find());
```

Answer (score 1):

Вариант первый:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    //удалять из списка строк все слова, содержащие букву «р»
    if (list.get(i).matches("^[^р]*$")) {
        System.out.println("Ok" + list.get(i));
    }
}
```

вариант второй использовать `!` при проверке выражения:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    //удалять из списка строк все слова, содержащие букву «р»
    if (!list.get(i).matches(".*р.*")) {
        System.out.println("Ok" + list.get(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: не работает( 
переписал на вот так "^[^р].*"
удаляет строки там где  в середине есть буква л, но не удаляет там где в начале слова есть буква л